# False positive number Bloom filter

Tags: python, dataframe, hash, bloom-filter

I implemented a bloom filter with 3 hash functions, and now I should calculate the exact number of false positives (not possibility) in that filter. Is there an efficient way to calculate that? The number of items in the filter is 200 million and the size of bit array is 400 million

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://hur.st/bloomfilter/

Comment: @Andrej Kesely No this gives the probability of false positive, I want the exact number of false positive in my bloom filter

Comment: The Bloom filter is a probabilistic data structure. By definition, you cannot compute the exact number of false positives that will occur in your Bloom filter, because it depends on the input. Even if you had a populated Bloom filter and you wanted to know how many keys would be falsely identified, it would be very difficult (depending on the key type, even impossible), because the range of possible keys is essentially infinite and you would have to check each one.

Comment: The question is unclear. The exact number of false positives in terms of keys, or in terms of hashes? For 32-hashes, you could calculate (using brute force). For keys: do you have the list of keys? Then you can calculate using a loop. If not, and assuming they are e.g. strings, you can't because the number of possible keys is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is very simple.

Count the number of bits that are 'on' and divide that by the total number of bits. This will give you your fill-rate.

When querying, all elements that were inserted earlier will hit 'on' bits and return positive. For elements which were not inserted into the filter, the probability of hitting an 'on' bit is your fill-rate. Therefore, with 3 hash functions, your error-rate will be (fill_rate^3).

Though 0.5 is the optimal fill-rate that maximizes space vs. error-rate, any other fill rate is possible but it will either take too much space or has a higher error-rate than required. So you may be better off using 4 hash functions with less space. It really depends on your use case. What is your requirement? what error-rate are you looking for?